# How can I paginate my items using custom search engine API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, google-custom-search

I'm fetching data from the Google Custom Search Engine API in my ReactJs App. I know this API only returns the first 100 results and each page is divided in 10 results each.

My variable `resultData.items` returns an array of 10 items with its URL, title, snippet and other properties.

This is what my variable `resultData.queries` returns. See that there is a property named `nextPage`:

```
{
  "request": [
    {
      "title": "Google Custom Search - google",
      "totalResults": "48240000000",
      "searchTerms": "google",
      "count": 10,
      "startIndex": 1,
      "inputEncoding": "utf8",
      "outputEncoding": "utf8",
      "safe": "off",
      "cx": "c5e7e9c901dcfe0b0"
    }
  ],
  "nextPage": [
    {
      "title": "Google Custom Search - google",
      "totalResults": "48240000000",
      "searchTerms": "google",
      "count": 10,
      "startIndex": 11,
      "inputEncoding": "utf8",
      "outputEncoding": "utf8",
      "safe": "off",
      "cx": "c5e7e9c901dcfe0b0"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I am storing my data:

```
const Search = () => {    
  
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [resultData, setResultData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(5);
  
  
 function searchInGoogle(e){
    
    const BASE_URL = `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1`
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_KEY;
    const SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY;    
    var apiCall = `${BASE_URL}?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY}&q=${searchText}`

    axios.get(apiCall).then(function (response){
      setIsLoading(true)
      console.log(response.data)
      setResultData(response.data)
      setIsLoading(false)
      

    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
      setIsLoading(false)
    })
    
  }

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value)
    
  }

  const handleNextPage = (e) => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
  }

  const handlePrevPage = (e) => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
    if(currentPage <= 0){
      document.getElementById('prevPage').hidden = true
    } else {
      document.getElementById('prevPage').hidden = false
    }
  }

  console.log(resultData.items)
  
  const items = resultData.items?.map((item)=>{
    return <Item key={item.id} title={item.title} description={item.snippet} url={item.formattedUrl}/>      
      
    }) ?? [] // return an empty array in case the result is undefined
  
  const searchInfo = resultData.searchInformation ? <p>About {resultData.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults} results ({resultData.searchInformation.formattedSearchTime} seconds)</p> : <p></p>
  

    const lastItemIndex = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const firstItemIndex = lastItemIndex - itemsPerPage;
    const totalPages = parseInt(searchInfo.formattedTotalResults) / itemsPerPage;
    console.log(totalPages)

    return (
    <div className='searchPage'>
      
      <Searchbar handleInputChange={handleInputChange} searchInGoogle={searchInGoogle} /> 
      <div>
        { (resultData.searchInformation && Object.keys(resultData.searchInformation)) !== 0 ? <>
            {searchInfo}
        </> : <p></p>  
        }
        {
        (resultData.items && Object.keys(resultData.items)) !== 0 ? <>
        {items}
        </> : <><p>No results</p></>
        }
      </div>
      <div className='pages'>
        <div className='pagination' id='prevPage'><button onClick={handlePrevPage}>Previous</button></div>
        <div className='pagination'>{currentPage}</div>
        <div className='pagination'><button onClick={handleNextPage}>Next</button></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

I know this API has in its JSON the properties `nextPage` and `previousPage` but i don´t know how to access them and how to relate them to my logic and display different items but always the same amount of items in different pages.
`previousPage` is not appearing in the object because it is the first page of results.
Any idea how to implement pagination using this API in reactjs?

Answer (score 0):

Google returns a maximum of 10 results at a time. If you look at the "nextPage" object returned in the response, you'll notice a **startIndex** parameter which is set to **11**. This parameter indicates the index of the first document that will be returned in the request for the next page.
You can specify which page you want by adding the **"&start="** parameter in your request url.

For example, say you want the second page of results. The nextPage object says that the first document in the second page will have an index = 11. So your query for the second page should look like this(assuming that you're using the custom JSON search api):

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={yourKey}&cx={yourSearchEngineId}?q={yourQuery}&start=11
```

This will return the second page of results. Similarly for the rest of the pages, just keep adding 10 to the value of the start parameter.

Hope this helps!